# Meu codigo so filtra se digitar primeira letra Jquery, como filtrar digitando a palavra inteira (tabela)?

Tags: html, jquery

Ex: palavra (ideal) se eu digitar na busca o "i" ele busca todas as palavra que contem a letra "i", Mas se eu digitar toda a palavra a busca some e fica em branco.

segue o código:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function () {
      var searchitem = $('#myInput').val();
      if (searchitem == null || searchitem == undefined){
          $('#table tbody td').show();

      }
      else {
          searchitem = searchitem.toUpperCase();
          $('#table tbody tr').hide();
          $('#table tbody tr').each(function () {
              if ($(this).text().indexOf(searchitem) >= 0) {
                  $(this).show();
              }
          });     
      }

  });
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta e elabore um [mcve]. Ao [edit] aproveite para descrever também como deve ser o comportamento do código quando a palavra só possua uma letra (exemplo: buscar pela palavra `é`).

Answer (score 0):

Falta algumas informações para poder dar uma resposta mais concreta mas espero que o exemplo abaixo possa te ajudar:

```js
$('#myInput').keyup(function () {
 const val = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
 $('#table td').each(function() {
  const tdText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
  if (tdText.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
   $(this).parent().show();
  } else {
   $(this).parent().hide();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<table id="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Lorem</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ipsum</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dolor</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sit</td></tr>
  <tr><td>amet</td></tr>
  <tr><td>consectetur</td></tr>
  <tr><td>adipisicing</td></tr>
  <tr><td>elit</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```